# Реализация двойного прыжка

Tags: c#, unity3d

Собственно в названии и заключается проблема. Код следующий:

```
private bool isGrounded = true;
private bool isAir = false;

private void Update()
{
    if (isGrounded) State = CharState.Idle;
    if (isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) Jump();
    //if (isAir && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) DoubleJump();
    //if (isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump + Jump")) DoubleJump();
}
private void Jump()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) DoubleJump();
    else { rigidbody.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse); }
    //rigidbody.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    //isAir = true; isGrounded = false;
}
private void DoubleJump()
{
    rigidbody.AddForce(2 * transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    //isAir = false;
    //isGrounded = true;
}
```

Последняя попытка была такой, но так при активации метода Jump персонаж сразу попадает в DoubleJump хотя должно быть не так.

Comment: А вы как хотите, что бы прыжок работал только с прыжка от земли. Или что бы при падении пригнуть можно было ещё раз?

Comment: Смотрите внимательнее, если в текущем кадре нажата кнопка "Jump", то выполняется метод `Jump()`, в котором точно такая же проверка, ведущая к вызову `DoubleJump()`. Получается в какой-то момент вы нажимаете на кнопку "Jump", поэтому оба условия выполняются и код переходит к выполнению `DoubleJump()`.

Comment: Сама идея такой реализации не самая правильная, без стейт машины не обойтись.

Comment: Хотелось бы чтобы прыгнуть можно было в любой точке прыжка. Да я понимаю что данный код срабатывает в одном кадре, но увы я не знаю как можно это разграничить. Знаний не хватает для других реализаций.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я согласен с комментарием под вопросом о том, что это не очень правильная реализация и лучше делать стейт-машину. Это не очень сложно и рекомендую погуглить примеры простейших стейт-машин (благо их навалом). Однако, если вы всё-таки хотите использовать такой подход, то, пожалуйста, попробуйте использовать этот код:

```
    private bool isGrounded = true;
    private bool canDoubleJump = true;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))//если нажата кнопка Jump
        {
            if (isGrounded)//проверяем, находится ли персонаж на земле
            {
                Jump();//если да, то прыгаем "первый" прыжок
            }
            else if (canDoubleJump)//если персонаж не приземлён и может прыгнуть ещё раз, то прыгаем "второй" прыжок
            {
                DoubleJump();
            }
            //если персонаж не приземлён и больше не может прыгать, то при нажатии кнопки Jump ничего не произойдёт
        }
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        isGrounded = false;//устанавливаем, что персонаж не приземлён
        canDoubleJump = true;//устанавливаем, что персонаж может прыгнуть "второй" раз
        rigidbody.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    private void DoubleJump()
    {
        canDoubleJump = false;//устанавливаем, что персонаж не может прыгнуть "второй" раз, пока не прыгнет "первый" раз
        rigidbody.AddForce(2 * transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    //этот метод должен вызываться при приземлении персонажа
    private void Landing()
    {
        isGrounded = true;//устанавливаем, что персонаж приземлён
        canDoubleJump = false;//устанавливаем, что персонаж не может прыгнуть "второй" раз, пока не прыгнет "первый"
    }
```

Comment: `State = CharState.DoubleJump;   //если надо` - что это и зачем оно нужно в данном коде?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker судя по всему это как раз какие-то зачатки для стейт-машины. Сделал так, чтобы показать где, по моему мнению, лучше присваивать стейты. Напомню, `State = CharState.Idle` в коде из вопроса находится в `Update()`.

Comment: Тогда это не очень правильно, нужно разделять поведение в зависимости от текущего состояния и смену стейтов, мешать их - неблагодарное дело.

Comment: Да этот код правильно работает, но если я быстро нажму несколько раз пробел, то персонаж улетает безумно высоко. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker автор уже написал, что "Знаний не хватает для других реализаций", поэтому, возможно, не стоит сильно усложнять его код, иначе он просто не сможет с ним нормально работать. В конце концов, он не спрашивал "Как создать простую стейт-машину", а попросил помощи разобраться с его небольшой проблемой.

Comment: Ну а зачем тогда тут вообще что-то, касающееся стейт машины?

Comment: @Александр не уверен почему могла возникнуть такая реакция. Код предусматривает 1 или 2 прыжка - не более. Возможно, сила с которой прыгает персонаж, слишком большая? Попробуйте поиграться с цифрами при вызове метода `rigidbody.AddForce(...)`

Comment: @RiotBr3aker если у автора есть какая-то логика, которая реагирует на смену "стейтов", однако он не показал её реализацию - имею ли я право удалять его логику, тем самым, возможно, ломая что-то в недрах кода, скрытых для меня? Я считаю, что нет. Если считаете, что я не прав, пусть так, всё может быть. Предлагаю не продолжать дискуссию, т.к. она немного не в тему.

Comment: Нет, она как раз в тему, потому что ваш ответ перегружен ненужной логикой, сюда придет другой человек с такой же проблемой и просто скопипастит это, а потом не поймет, почему у него ничего не работае. Если вы чего-то не поняли в вопросе - нужно уточнить.

Comment: @MikhailDeyman, я как раз убрал умножение на 2 в DoubleJump и если я прыгаю 1 раз и в полете прыгаю еще раз то все прекрасно, но если находясь на земле я несколько раз нажму прыжок, то персонаж улетает, аналогично происходит если я пытаюсь прыгнуть в полете над препятствиями (при нескольких нажатиях), иначе все хорошо

Comment: @RiotBr3aker как вы считаете, как мне лучше "усесться" на оба стула и сделать так, чтобы и автор понял, куда "переехала" его логика, и новоприбывшие копипастеры не обломались? Стоит закомментить участок с той логикой?

Comment: 2 стула: 1) написать работающий код вообще без стейтов. 2) уточнить у автора ВСЮ логику и уже на ее основе написать ответ.

Comment: @Александр возможно ошибка где-то в отслеживании приземления, которое вы не показали. Может быть персонаж ошибочно считается "приземлённым" до тех пор, пока не наберёт какую-то определённую высоту. Опишите, пожалуйста, как у вас проиходит отлавливание приземления?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker вы меня убедили, впредь буду осторожнее, спасибо. Код в ответе поправил, убрав излишнюю логику.

Comment: Если я правильно Вас понял, то так: private void CheckGround()
    {
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, 0.3F);

        isGrounded = colliders.Length > 1;

        if (!isGrounded) State = CharState.Jump;
    }. Но я не вызываю этот метод в update

Comment: @Александр во-первых, возможно радиус проверки соседних коллайдеров (`Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll()`) слишком большой. Также, попробуйте повтыкать в дебаг-логи для проверки, что происходит при том или ином действии (например в `Jump()` можно вставить `Debug.Log("вызван метод Jump()")` - так вы поймёте когда метод вызывается, а когда - нет)
во-вторых, во время приземления вы кажется забыли помимо `isGrounded` менять ещё и `canDoubleJump`.

Comment: @Александр, откуда вы взяли этот код? Вы точно понимаете, как работает `CharState` и для чего он вообще нужен?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, код взял из интернета с проекта который нашел и да я не понимаю для чего он нужен